# Fetch data time out on cpanel using node js with mongo (Driver: Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cpanel

I hosted node js application on cpanel. I insert data to mongo there that works fine when I fetch data from db(mongo) it times out.

The error is

```
{
    "code": 403,
    "status": "Error",
    "message": "Operation `user.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"
}
```

I also hosted the app on aws server that works fine.

Comment: var uri = 'mongodb+srv://mongo-user:yourpassword@cluster0.rbmyn.mongodb.net/qr-db-in?retryWrites=true&w=majority&keepAlive=true&poolSize=30&autoReconnect=true&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000';
mongoose.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this was due the blocked port of mongodb.